# Octave: Install symbolic package, 'int' undefined

Tags: ubuntu, integration, octave, symbols

I successfully installed symbolic package with `sudo apt-get install octave-symbolic`, but still it doesn;t recogbize the int function for integration:

```
octave:7> symbols
octave:8> x=sym('x')
x =

x
octave:9> int('x')
error: `int' undefined near line 9 column 1
```

So, how can I use the integration function? Is the function different from MATLAB?

Comment: I don't think the symbolic package as implemented that function yet. It's not listed on the [package function reference](http://octave.sourceforge.net/symbolic/index.html). Maybe you could write it and give it to the Octave developers.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The integrate function has not been implemented in the symbolic toolbox as of v1.1.0. Type the command

```
pkg describe -verbose symbolic
```

at the Octave prompt to see a list of all the available commands in symbolic. Under Calculus there is only `differentiate` thus far.

Answer (score 0):

please try int32(x) or any other int you need like uint8, uint16.
http://www.gnu.org/software/octave/doc/interpreter/Integer-Data-Types.html

Comment: Thanks, but I wan't looking for integer conversion. In MATLAB, int('x') ( symbolic ) will integrate on its input symbolic function! My question is that why symbolic integration doesn't work in octave?